# VB.NET: How to load the following values from a string into a collection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

i have a string = `"/a/value1/x/valueforx/b/value2/c/value3"`

the keys a, b, and c can be in any order in the string that is coming in and will always be separated by a slash.

What i need to do is to find `a, b, c` and then add their values to a `collection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Uwe Keim said, use `String.Split`.  What I would do is make a quick function that returns a dictionary.

This code is untested, but should get you started...

```
Public Function GetConfigFromMagicString(ByVal sSource as string) as Dictionary(of String, string)
    Dim ConfigDict as Dictionary (of String, String)
    Dim Pieces as string() = sSource.split("/")
    For x as Integer = 0 to Pieces.Length-1 Step 2
        ConfigDict.add(pieces(x), pieces(x+1)
    Next x
    return ConfigDict
End Function
```

From there, you just retrieve it like this...

```
Dim myConfig as Dictionary (of string, string) = getConfigFromMagicString("a/value1/x/valueforx/b/value2/c/value3")
msgbox(myConfig.Item("a"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) function.

Then iterate through the results and pick up each that you want to retrieve.

E.g. something like (C#):

```
var splitted = "/a/value1/x/valueforx/b/value2/c/value3".Split('/');

for ( var index = 0; index<splitted.Length; ++index )
{
    if ( s=="a" )
    {
        var valueOfA = s[index+1];
        // Process valueOfA.
    }

    // Same for "b" and "c".
}
```

The same in VB.NET:

```
Dim splitted = "/a/value1/x/valueforx/b/value2/c/value3".Split("/"C)

For index As Integer = 0 To splitted.Length - 1
    If s = "a" Then
        ' Process valueOfA.
        Dim valueOfA = s(index + 1)

        ' Same for "b" and "c".
    End If
Next
```

I omitted error checking here (i.e. array bounds checks)

Comment: there could be other values that i don't want such as g/value

Comment: and i only want to add the three values of a, b, c into the collection in that order

Comment: i guess my question is how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This should cover the basics of the algorithm. It'll need a little cleaning to make sure that there aren't any unexpected conditions that may throw exceptions.

```
Dim myDict as Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim myStr as String = "/a/value1/b/value2/c/value3"

Dim temp() As String = myStr.Split("/"c)

For i As Integer = 0 to temp.Length Step 2
    'Assumes that it will always be an array length divisible by
    '2. If this is not the case, logic is necessary to prevent
    'for loop from bombing at the end of the sequence

    'EDIT: for clarification
    Select Case temp(i)
        Case "a", "b", "c"
            myDict(temp(i)) = temp(i + 1)

        DefaultCase
            Continue
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "/a/value1/b/value2/c/value3";
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
string[] strList = s.Split(new char[]{'/'} ,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i <= strList.Length - 2 ; i += 2)
  {
    KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue = 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>   (strList[i] , strList[i + 1]);
    kvList.Add(keyValue);


   }
```

it is C#..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then use this:

```
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("/a/value1/x/valueforx/b/value2/c/value3", "(?<=/[abc]/)[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

To put these matches into a string collection as requested you can just add this after the above code:

```
Dim sc As New Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
For Each m As Match In mc
  sc.Add(m.Value)
Next
```

Using your input this produces matches with values of

- value1
- value2
- value3